# How to use (wix) torch msbuild task?

Tags: msbuild, wix, wix3.5, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I am trying to build patches (msp) from Wix.

One of the step specifies that i have to use Torch task to create wixmst.

I was looking for torch task in Wix.targets. The task exists but there is no documentation for that task.

Can any one used torch task in their Msbuild script? If so please help me how to use that?

My intention is to create wixmst file using torch task . Through exe we can do it like below.

```
“torch.exe -p -xi 1.0\Product.wixpdb 1.1\Product.wixpdb -out Patch\Diff.Wixmst”
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source for the Torch task can be found here:

http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a782416c7fbc#src%2fWixTasks%2fTorch.cs

So the command line options map to properties on the task as follows:

```
-notidy         LeaveTemporaryFiles
-xo             OutputAsXml
-xi             InputIsXml
-p              PreserveUnmodifiedContent
-out            OutputFile
-a              adminImage
-x              BinaryExtractionPath
-serr           SuppressTransformErrorFlags
-t              TransformValidationType
-val            TransformValidationFlags
<targetInput>   BaselineFile
<updatedInput>  UpdateFile
```

So your command line might look something like this:

```
  <Target Name="DoTorch">
    <!-- torch.exe -p -xi 1.0\Product.wixpdb 1.1\Product.wixpdb -out Patch\Diff.Wixmst -->
    <Torch PreserveUnmodifiedContent="true" 
           InputIsXml="true"
           BaselineFile="$(TargetFile)"
           UpdateFile="$(UpdateFile)"
           OutputFile="$(PatchOutputFile)" />     
  </Target>
```

Comment: Or you could call the version of the torch.exe you use without parameters and it would print a full list of commands.